# Mutex and Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, mutex

Here's my problem.
Windows Phone 8.1    Visual Studio 2013 Release 4

I've got a main project, and a background project that runs every 30 minutes. I want to pass data between the two. I want to ensure exclusive access to storage in Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings, so I'm using a Mutex.

In my main XAML project, I create and use a Mutex named "B+DBgMu" (don't ask).

```
public static Mutex Mu = null;      // A Mutex
Mu = new Mutex (true, "B+DBgMu");   // Create a Mutex. This is done only once.

if (App.Mu.WaitOne (200))           // Wait for exclusive access. This is done often.
{
    < PROTECTED CODE GOES HERE>

    App.Mu.ReleaseMutex ();     // Release our lock on application storage.
}
```

I reliably get the Mutex and access to the shared storage.

In my background project, I attempt to (I think) acquire the same Mutex, only the Mutex is never acquired:

```
Mutex Mu = new Mutex (false, "B+DBgMu");    // Hook onto the Mutex.
if (Mu.WaitOne (1000))              // Wait (quite a while) for it.
{
    < PROTECTED CODE GOES HERE
    and it NEVER EXECUTES>

    App.Mu.ReleaseMutex ();         // Release our lock.
}
```

I've scoured the Web, especially StackOverflow, but I wonder how much of what's there applies to the Windows Phone.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```
   Mu = new Mutex (true, "B+DBgMu");   // Create a Mutex. This is done only once.
```

Using *true* here is your bug.  That gives your main thread immediate ownership of the Mutex.  Mutex is re-entrant, calling WaitOne() next simply increments the usage count.  And calling ReleaseMutex() simply decrements it.  It never goes to zero.

So your main thread *always* owns the mutex and your background worker can never acquire it.  Simple fix, pass *false* instead.

Comment: Thank you. 'false' is the phrase that pays!