# Mutex and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, mutex

I want to prevent my Background Process from performing an action if the app is open in the foreground. I found a similar question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534243/mutex-and-windows-phone-8-1), but I can't get it to work for me. When my Background Process checks the Mutex, it is never already in existence. When the foreground app starts I create a Mutex like so:

```
public void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    var myMutex = new Mutex(false, "MUTEX_NAME");
}
```

I release it when the foreground app closes:

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var myMutex = new Mutex(false, "MUTEX_NAME");
    myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

In the Background Process I have the following check:

```
bool IsMutexLocked()
{
    var myMutex = new Mutex(false, "MUTEX_NAME"); 
    return myMutex.WaitOne(100); 
}
```

I'm assuming here that `WaitOne` returns true if `"MUTEX_NAME"` doesn't exist, or it does exist but gets released after 100ms. I've also tried using the `out createdNew` in the Mutex constructor, and the static methods `OpenExisting`and `TryOpenExisting` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not locking your mutex in main app, you just create it (also without ownership). You can either create Mutex with initial ownership or call *WaitOne()* when needed. Some more help [at Joe Alabhari's blog](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex).

```
public void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    var myMutex = new Mutex(true, "MUTEX_NAME");
    // or call myMutex.WaitOne() // here maybe some timeout handling
}
```

Also I don't think that holding a mutex until the app is closed is a good practise - lock the mutex only when you really need to (for example access to common file). If you really want to try this, create a global mutex instance upon launching, then release it upon closing, but without obtaining it again, just use previous instance.

Look out for couple of things - don't leave abandoned mutexes, look out so it's not garbage collected, release it when needed. There are plenty of posts about this synchronization object, [here you have a good pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/2681948).

Comment: Thanks that worked! A follow up question, if the foreground app crashes will the mutex get released?

Comment: @kernanb No, it won't be automatically release. Take a look at the patterns - relesing is in every case in *finally* block, in that case mutex is released regardless there was exception or not.